# Prove absolute convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{f(n)}$ if $f$ is increasing and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ is absolutely convergent

Tags: real-analysis

**Synopsis**

In Terence Tao's, *Analysis 1*, we are given the following exercise:

> Let $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ be an  absolutely convergent series of real numbers. Let $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be an increasing function. Show that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{f(n)}$ is also an absolutely convergent series.

I would like someone to help verify my proof.

**Proof**

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ is absolutely convergent, we know by the Cauchy Convergence Criterion that there exists some $M \geq 0$ such that for all $p,q \geq M$ we have $$ \sum_{n=p}^q |a_n|  \leq \epsilon.$$ Note, however, that $\displaystyle\sum_p^q |a_{f(n)}| \leq \sum_{f(p)}^{f(q)} |a_n|$ for all $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$ (since each term is positive and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $n \leq f(n)$ since $f$ is increasing), so if $p,q \geq M$, we obtain $$\displaystyle\sum_p^q |a_{f(n)}| \leq \displaystyle\sum_{f(p)}^{f(q)} |a_n| \leq \epsilon$$ since $f(p),f(q) \geq M$. Hence, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{f(n)}$ is also absolutely convergent by the Cauchy Convergence Criterion.

Comment: Maybe you want to rewrite this: "we know by the Cauchy Convergence Criterion that for any index n, there exists some index M≥f(n) such that..."?

Comment: @AsemAbdelraouf True. It sounds awkward and is kind of unnecessary. I'll rewrite it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means you have to prove $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_{f(k)}$$ $$=\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_{f(1)}+...+a_{f(n)})$$ is absolutely convergent where $f:\mathbb N \mapsto \mathbb N$ is strictly increasing function.
I am giving my argument through an example.

Let $f(n)=n^2$. Then $\sum a_{n^2}=a_1+a_4+a_9+...=a_1+0+0+a_4+0+0+0+0+a_9+...=\sum b_n$ where $a_n=b_n$ if $n$ is a perfect square number and $b_n=0$ otherwise.

$\sum |a_n|$ is convergent.
Since $0\le |b_n|\le |a_n|  \forall n \in \mathbb N$, by Comparison Test $\sum b_n=\sum a_{n^2}$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: This is a good alternative proof to mine. To generalize your example (which I'm sure you mean as a hint), I'll define $b_n := a_n$ if $n \in f(\mathbb{N})$ and $b_n=0$ otherwise. Then the same argument works. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry you asked me to verify your proof.  There are many one for that. But I'm wondering wether my informal proof will be accepted or not. At last this is Real Analysis,  the field of extreme rigour.

Comment: Yes please write my proof in the language of Analysis,  make it rigorous

Comment: Ah! I'm a novice at mathematics, but I think it works! If you take my generalization above, I believe it would be a good proof. I didn't even think of using the limit comparison test, so thank you for that idea :)

Comment: Just edit your proof so that you're not using an example, but you're defining your sequence $b_n$ in the way I defined it in my first comment. Then your proof should be good!

Comment: Ok I'm now a bit busy. I will edit it some hours later.

Comment: Alright! Good luck :3